# Bind a complex type property to a primary type

Tags: c#, json, .net-5

Suppose I have a ViewModel in .net core client,

```
public class MyViewModel{
   ...
   public List<MyClass> NamesList{get;set;}
   ...
}
```

where MyClass is defined as below,

```
public class MyClass{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Now if my api endpoint(POST request) expects a model as below,

```
public class MyApiModel{
   ...
   public List<string> NamesList{get;set;}
   ...
}
```

how to bind `List<MyClass>` to `List<string>` by using **Name** property of **MyClass**

Note - 1) Using duplicate property in client or api would not be a good solution I feel
2) Using a different ViewModel with `List<string>` as a property type and copy the fields before POSTing to api is also not suitable in this case because if the request fails, I would require the old model to pass it to the view with model errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need different data structures, you'll need different classes. This is quite common. So the question seems to be more about how to map structure A to structure B.

There are multiple options:

- Libraries like automapper: https://automapper.org/
- Write your own code

For DTOs (like your api model class) I'd take a look at C# records https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records which are perfect for such dtos.

```
 public record MyApiModel(List<string> Names)
 {
     public static MyApiModel From(Model model) 
         => return new(model.NamesList.Select(n => n.Name));
 }
```

One nice effect of using the constructor to set all data is, that the compiler will show you all places that needs to be updated if you modify your models.